# get first two digits by using split method in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to split one output. the output is

```
02|05|002|004|0014|0035|R
```

I tried with

```
$state.ToString().Split("|")[0]
```

i got the result like `System.Object[]`

i want to split the output and assigning to variables like

```
$a='02'
$b='05'
```

please help me to complete this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them to the array using `select -first`

```
$state = '02|05|002|004|0014|0035|R'
$list = @()
$list = $state.ToString().Split("|") | select -First 2
[string] $a = $list[0]
[string] $b = $list[1]
write-host $a
write-host $b
```

Comment: I used like this $list = "$state".ToString().Split("|") [string] $a = $statecode[0] [string] $b = $statecode[1]
  [string] $c = $statecode[2]
  [string] $d = $statecode[3]
  [string] $e = $statecode[4] write-host $a
  write-host $b
  write-host $c
  write-host $d
  write-host $e finally i got it. thanx vasja

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simplified solution that uses the range operator to return the first two elements and assign them to variables:

```
$a,$b = '02|05|002|004|0014|0035|R'.Split('|')[0..1]
```